# What do I do after dpkg segfaults installing nautilus-dropbox?

Tags: apt, nautilus, dpkg, dropbox

I tried installing `nautilus-dropbox` on a freshly installed Ubuntu 17.10 and received the error

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg received a segmentation fault.
```

`/var/log/dpkg.log` does not mention dropbox at all so I suspect it's left over from the initial install of Ubuntu.

`/var/log/apt/history` says (at the end)

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-28  10:11:49 Commandline: apt install
nautilus-dropbox Requested-By: braun (1000) Install:
libindicator7:amd64 (16.10.0+16.10.20160913-0ubuntu1, automatic),
python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu2, automatic), python2.7:amd64
(2.7.14-2ubuntu2, automatic), python-cairo:amd64 (1.8.8-2.2,
automatic), nautilus-dropbox:amd64 (2015.10.28-1ubuntu2), python:amd64
(2.7.14-2ubuntu1, automatic), libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1,
automatic), libappindicator1:amd64 (12.10.1+17.04.20170215-0ubuntu2,
automatic), python-gtk2:amd64 (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu1, automatic),
python-gpgme:amd64 (0.3-1.2build2, automatic), python-gobject-2:amd64
(2.28.6-12ubuntu2, automatic), python-minimal:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1,
automatic) Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg received a segmentation
fault. End-Date: 2018-01-28  10:11:55
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then post output here.